# How to supply variables to terraform destroy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to destroy some aws resources created using Terraform. I have my region set as a variable in my provider resource like this

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
```

I have the variable set empty by default because I only supply them using a json file during terraform plan/apply.

Now when I run `terraform destroy`, it says `Error: Invalid AWS Region:`.

I checked if we can supply variables during destroy but sadly we cannot.
I also checked if we can destroy using the applied plan, we cannot do this either.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your value for `var.aws_region`? Do you have an environment variable set for the region? "I checked if we can supply variables during destroy but sadly we cannot. I also checked if we can destroy using the applied plan, we cannot do this either." You can definitely do both of these. What errors are you seeing when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue with Terraform 0.15.0 that is fixed on the version 0.15.1, you can update your terraform for this new version and try again. To read more about this issue, take a look [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8040).

As a workaround you can try to set `AWS_REGION` env before running the `terraform destroy`

```
AWS_REGION=us-west-2 terraform destroy
```

or ending adding the region manually:

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-1"
}
```